# remove parentheses only when they are there

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have google sheets, and trying to create a function that will only get rid of the () when they are there and times the number by a negative only when i get rid of the (), but if i don't have any or don't get rid of any it can just go on and complete the function i have below.

```
=IF(RIGHT('Cash Flow'!B17,1)="B",LEFT('Cash Flow'!B17,LEN('Cash Flow'!B17)-1)\*1000000000,IF(RIGHT('Cash Flow'!B17,1)="M",LEFT('Cash Flow'!B17,LEN('Cash Flow'!B17)-1)\*1000000,'Cash Flow'!B17))
```

Answer (score 2):

you can remove parenthesis this way:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(B1; "[\(\)]"; )
```

[image]

Comment: Inside a character class, parentheses require no escaping, so `=regexreplace(B1; "[()]"; "")` would be easier on the eye.